# Display Object Output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, output

I've been having trouble with this part of my assignment. I have most of it coded but I have been having trouble implementing this last part:

Write a loop that simulates checkouts and checkins for a 3 month period. Every day iterate over the catalog, and every person in the patrons array. If the patron currently has the book checked out then check it in. If it is not checked out then add it to the patrons list of books via the patrons read method. If the book is overdue then add a fine of $5.00 to the patron returning it. At the end of the 3 month period, display each patron, the books they have currently checked out and any fine they may have.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
//Author class
var Author = function(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
};

var Book = function(title, Available, publicationDate, checkoutDate, callNumber, Authors) {
  this.title = title;
  this.Available = Available;
  this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
  this.checkoutDate = checkoutDate;
  this.callNumber = callNumber;
  this.Authors = Authors;
};
Book.prototype.checkOut = function() {
  this.Available = false;
  var temp = new Date(1000000000);
  var d = new Date() - temp;
  var res = new Date(d);
  this.checkoutDate = res;
};
Book.prototype.isOverdue = function() {
  //Get 1 day in milliseconds
  var singleDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var todayDate = new Date().getTime();
  var difference = todayDate - this.checkoutDate.getTime();
  if (Math.round(difference / singleDay) >= 14) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

var Patron = function(firstName, lastName, libraryCardNumber, booksOut, fine) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.libraryCardNumber = libraryCardNumber;
  this.booksOut = booksOut;
  this.fine = fine;
};
Patron.prototype.read = function(book) {
  this.booksOut.add(book);
}
Patron.prototype.read = function(book) {
  this.booksOut.remove(this.booksOut.length);
}
//creating author objects
var authors = []
authors[0] = new Author("Neil", "Armstrong");
authors[1] = new Author("Hard", "Popeye");

var mybooks = []
mybooks[0] = new Book('gravity', true, new Date(2000, 5, 20), new Date(), 10, authors);
mybooks[1] = new Book('munro', true, new Date(2000, 5, 20), new Date(), 11, authors);
mybooks[2] = new Book('kohli', true, new Date(2000, 5, 20), new Date(), 12, authors);
mybooks[3] = new Book('sachin', true, new Date(2000, 5, 20), new Date(), 13, authors);
mybooks[4] = new Book('sehwag', true, new Date(2000, 5, 20), new Date(), 14, authors);

var patrons = []
patrons[0] = new Patron('master', 'jumbo', 1, mybooks, 0.00);
patrons[1] = new Patron('kyle', 'munro', 1, mybooks, 0.00);
patrons[2] = new Patron('master', 'jumbo2', 1, mybooks, 0.00);
patrons[3] = new Patron('master', 'jumbo3', 1, mybooks, 0.00);
patrons[4] = new Patron('master', 'jumbo4', 1, mybooks, 0.00);

var j = 0;
while (j < patrons.length) {
  var books = patrons[j].booksOut;
  var fine = patrons[j].fine;
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    if (books[i].isOverdue()) {
      fine = fine + 5.00;
    }
  }
  patrons[j].fine = fine;
  console.log(patrons[0]);
}
```

The problem is it outputs the same object over and over again infinitely. Why does the happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem and what have you done to try and solve it?

Comment: I just need the output to display each Patron's name, books they have checked out and fines but I haven't been able to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Based on what you've learned in class, how do you output stuff? `console.log`? `document.write`? Perhaps querying for an element and updating it's text contents. Output comes in multiple formats, it all depends on how you and your teacher want it to be displayed.

Comment: console.log I know how to output things its just that when I output "Patron" it doesn't output correctly

Comment: Can you show us in your code how you are trying to output?

Comment: var j=0;
while(j < patrons.length){
var books = patrons[j].booksOut;
var fine = patrons[j].fine;
for(var i=0;i<books.length;i++){
if(books[i].isOverdue()){
fine = fine + 5.00;
}
}
patrons[j].fine = fine;
console.log(patrons[0]);
}

Comment: Why didn't you include your output code in your original code? Also, what are you seeing when you output `patrons[0]`? What do you expect to see?

Comment: { firstName: 'master',
  lastName: 'jumbo',
  libraryCardNumber: 1,
  booksOut:
   [ { title: 'gravity',
       Available: true,
       publicationDate: Tue Jun 20 2000 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time
),
       checkoutDate: Fri Jul 08 2016 12:36:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
       callNumber: 10,
       Authors: [Object] },
     { title: 'munro',
       Available: true,
       publicationDate: Tue Jun 20 2000 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time
),

Comment: checkoutDate: Fri Jul 08 2016 12:36:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
       callNumber: 11,
       Authors: [Object] },
     { title: 'kohli',
       Available: true,
       publicationDate: Tue Jun 20 2000 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time
),
       checkoutDate: Fri Jul 08 2016 12:36:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
       callNumber: 12,
       Authors: [Object] },

Comment: { title: 'sachin',
       Available: true,
       publicationDate: Tue Jun 20 2000 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time
),
       checkoutDate: Fri Jul 08 2016 12:36:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
       callNumber: 13,
       Authors: [Object] },
     { title: 'sehwag',
       Available: true,
       publicationDate: Tue Jun 20 2000 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time
),
       checkoutDate: Fri Jul 08 2016 12:36:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
       callNumber: 14,
       Authors: [Object] } ],
  fine: 0 }

Comment: Repeat that times infinity

Comment: @dungo So what's the problem? Those are your objects. Now you need to print out the relevant information.

Comment: you did not increment j's value in while(j < patrons.length). that is why you are getting infinite output.

Answer (score 2):

I have tweaked your code and show you a way to generate the output. As it is **an assignment problem** I have no intention to solve it totally. Modify it to get the expected output. Tell us if you have more problem.

```js
//Author class
var Author = function(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
};

var Book = function(title, Available, publicationDate, checkoutDate, callNumber, Authors) {
  this.title = title;
  this.Available = Available;
  this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
  this.checkoutDate = checkoutDate;
  this.callNumber = callNumber;
  this.Authors = Authors;
};

Book.prototype.checkOut = function(){
  this.Available = false;
  var temp = new Date(1000000000);
  var d = new Date()-temp;
  var res = new Date(d);
  this.checkoutDate = res;
};

Book.prototype.isOverdue = function(){
  //Get 1 day in milliseconds
  var singleDay=1000*60*60*24;
  var todayDate = new Date().getTime();
  var difference = todayDate - this.checkoutDate.getTime();
  if(Math.round(difference/singleDay) >= 14){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

var Patron = function(firstName, lastName, libraryCardNumber, booksOut, fine) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.libraryCardNumber = libraryCardNumber;
  this.booksOut = booksOut;
  this.fine = fine;
};

Patron.prototype.read = function(book){
  this.booksOut.add(book);
}

Patron.prototype.read = function(book){
  this.booksOut.remove(this.booksOut.length);
}

//creating author objects
var authors = []
authors[0] = new Author("Neil","Armstrong");
authors[1] = new Author("Hard","Popeye");

var mybooks = []
mybooks[0] = new Book('gravity',true,new Date(2000,5,20), new Date(), 10,authors);
mybooks[1] = new Book('munro',true,new Date(2000,5,20), new Date(), 11,authors);
mybooks[2] = new Book('kohli',true,new Date(2000,5,20), new Date(), 12,authors);
mybooks[3] = new Book('sachin',true,new Date(2000,5,20), new Date(), 13,authors);
mybooks[4] = new Book('sehwag',true,new Date(2000,5,20), new Date(), 14,authors);

var patrons = []
patrons[0] = new Patron('master','jumbo',1,mybooks,0.00);
patrons[1] = new Patron('kyle','munro',1,mybooks,0.00);
patrons[2] = new Patron('master','jumbo2',1,mybooks,0.00);
patrons[3] = new Patron('master','jumbo3',1,mybooks,0.00);
patrons[4] = new Patron('master','jumbo4',1,mybooks,0.00);

var j=0;
while(j < patrons.length){
  var books = patrons[j].booksOut;
  var fine = patrons[j].fine;
  for(var i=0;i<books.length;i++){
    if(books[i].isOverdue()){
      fine = fine + 5.00;
    }
  }
  patrons[j].fine = fine;
  j++;
}

for(i=0; i < patrons.length;i++){
  console.log(patrons[i].firstName+" has taken the following books:");
  for(j=0;j<patrons[i].booksOut.length;j++){
    console.log(patrons[i].booksOut[j].title);
  }
  console.log(patrons[i].firstName+" has fine = "+patrons[i].fine);
}
```